# How to get only the _Hex Value

Tags: reactjs, metamask, ethers.js, bignumber.js

I have a project in react.js

The next code

```
console.log(ethers.utils.parseEther('100'.toString()))
```

Give me the next result in the console

```
BigNumber {_hex: '0x056bc75e2d63100000', _isBigNumber: true}
```

I want only giveme the hex value 0x056bc75e2d63100000

i try use `'100'.toHexString()` but giveme the next error

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: '100'.toHexString is not a function
```

Answer (score -1):

If your value is a number, you can cast it as a hex string with `toString` method.

```js
const myNumber = 100
const myNumberHexString = myNumber.toString(16)
```

If your value is not a number, cast it as one first.

Comment: That giveme result of '64' i need that result '0x056bc75e2d63100000', this is a ethers.utils.parseEther

Comment: OP already has the hex. Read the question.